# Generar PDF en base a codigo HTML

Tags: javascript, pdf, ionic-framework, base64

me encuentro en un problema y recurro a ustedes para ver posibles soluciones.

Trabajo en una aplicación con Ionic (v1) y dentro de la app tengo un template HTML prototipo, de uno de los flujos sale la data que nosotros mostramos en el pdf. Obtengo el codigo html del template asi

```
$http.get('app/modules/Test/views/comprobante.html', {
    cache: $templateCache
})
.then(function(result) {
     console.log(result.data);

});
```

El valor de `result.data` es el codigo HTML puro y para reemplazar los valores utilizo palabras claves y las remplazo con el tipico `replace`

Esto funciona muy bien, ademas utilizamos un plugin `pdf-generator` para de todo ese texto HTML obtenemos un archivo pdf en base64 y eso lo subimos al servidor.

Ahora bien, se nos solicito ademas la versión web de la aplicación (`browser`) y como saben, los plugins cordova que no tienen soporte para esta platforma simplemente no funcionan, por lo que este proceso que explique no funciona. Intente implementar la libreria `jsPDF` pero no cumple con lo que necesito, de ese texto html que obtengo no genera un PDF correcto, más bien vacio y me imagino que es porque no interpreta el codigo html como tal.

Existirá alguna manera de hacer este proceso desde javascript? Obtener desde un archivo HTML un pdf en base64 y luego poder subirlo al servidor?

Quedo atento a cualquier duda.

Comment: Creo que en [StackOverflow en Inglés] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript) puede estar la solución a tu duda :)

Comment: La vi, pero lamentablemente no me sirve, si te fijas ahi obtienen el html desde el DOM, yo tengo el html como archivo y lo modifico como explique en mi pregunta :(

Comment: Bueno, [esta API](https://pdflayer.com/) se supone que vale para pasar HTML **puro** a PDF, no sé si aceptará las modificaciones que le haces, pero a lo mejor te sirve

Comment: me gustaría escribir un simple comentario pero todavía no tengo la reputación suficiente ;-). ¿Te has cerciorado de que no te genera PDF?. Quiero decir, que lo mires en la DOM (F12 del navegador). A mi pasó que me generaba el PDF pero no había definido bien el height y el width y sólo tuve que definirlos para visualizarlo y darme cuenta que funcionaba bien pero no se visualizaba por esta chorrada. Mediante la consulta de DOM puedes ves si te ha generado algo,eso ya lo sabrás.